# Check if Panda DataFrame cell contains a symbol

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 5666 rows. I need to check if it contains a symbol `#` and if so, take out a symbol I added to it, `_`. Right now, I'm adding a column `note_features['chord_label'] = note_features['bass'] + '_' + 'M'`.

I have a row that will equal `F_M` and that's fine, but I have another row that equals `F#_M`. I want to take out the `_` so it equals `F#M`. How can I do this?

thank you

Comment: '_' comes always just after '#' ? And if yes you want to remove just this '_' or all '_' in the cell (in case there are mor than one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Column":["F#_M","F_M"]})
output
    Column
0   F#_M
1   F_M

df.Column.apply(lambda x: x.replace("#","") if "#" in x else x)
# output
0    F_M
1    F_M
Name: Column

OR 

df.Column.apply(lambda x: x.replace("_","") if "#" in x else x)
# output
0    F#M
1    F_M
Name: Column
```

Does that help you achieve ur transformation?

What `apply` does is apply on each row a certain function. Our function is `lambda` which `replace`s a `character` of our choice by `something` else. In our case it was an `_` by an `empty` string.
`x.replace("#","") if # in x` <=> if the row contains a `#`, replace it by `empty`. `ELSE` keep `x` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work (even if there are other occurencies of '#" in the string, however it will only consider the first occurence of '#_' if there are multiple):

```
note_features['chord_label']=note_features['chord_label'].apply(lambda x: x[:x.index('#_')+1]+x[x.index('#')+2:] if '#_' in x else x)
```